# Mockito unable to verify invocation in thread run

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I'm trying to test a Runnable class, but unable to verify the inside class invocation. But through debug mode, I can see "k.put(c);" is touched.

Does anyone know why there is Mockito can't find invocation for "verify(k).put(any(C.class));" and how to get it verified?

Class to be tested

```
public class SampleClass implements Runnable {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SampleClass.class);

    private K k;

    @Inject
    public SampleClass (final K k) {
        this.k = k;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!k.isFinished()) {
            final C c = k.pull();

            if (c == null) {
                break;
            }

            k.put(c);
        }
    }
}
```

TestClass

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SampleClassTest extends TestBase {

    @Mock
    private K k;

    private SampleClass sampleClass;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        sampleClass = new SampleClass(k);
    }

    @Test
    public void testRun() {
        // Prepare
        when(k.isFinished()).thenReturn(false);
        final C c = buildC();
        when(k.pull()).thenReturn(c);
        ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

        // Run
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(sampleClass, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        // Verify
        verify(k).put(any(C.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not actually running your `Runnable` before the verification step. Rather you are scheduling it to be run at a later time. If you replaced your scheduler with a call of `sampleClass.run()` I expect the `verify` will then pass.

Comment: Your addition 'through debug mode, I can see "k.put(c);" is touched' is just proving that eventually the scheduler executes the code. That's not before verification however

Comment: A simple way to demonstrate this is to put a `Thread.sleep(100);` before your `verify`. You should get a `TooManyActualInvocations` error.

Comment: @sprinter yeah, thanks for the suggestions. But by directly calling sampleClass.run(), it will just running an infinite loop since I set "when(k.isFinished()).thenReturn(false);" And by using Thread.sleep(100), it will throw TooManyActualInvocations.Is there a good way to avoid that?

Comment: Yep I'll add an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not actually running your `Runnable` before the verification step. Rather you are scheduling it to be run at a later time.

Fortunately Mockito provides a way to wait for a response:

```
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(sampleClass, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
verify(k, timeout(100).atLeastOnce()).put(any(C.class));
```

Comment: I'm going to use the first approach, didn't aware that there is atLeast(1) that I can use. Super helpful!

Comment: @TommyQu actually when I checked the doc I realised Mockito provides an easier way. Have changed my answer to reflect that.